# How to return values from a callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have this code:

```
request({ uri: url }, function(err, response, body) {
  $ = cheerio.load(body);

  var stringOfNames = $('td').text().replace(/\n+/gm, " ");
  var namesArr = stringOfNames.split(" ");

  return namesArr;
});
```

which later I want to do module.export so I can use it in other modules.  However, how can I access the namesArr returned by the callback?

Comment: You can't. Return a promise instead.

Comment: any idea on how to do that? do I have to use a library?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=node+javascript+promises+tutorial

Comment: thanks. i'll read through it

Comment: See possible duplicates [return ajax result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) and [asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-undefined-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function)